# Angular Multiselect Dropdown | Sort Alphabetically

Tags: angularjs, multi-select

I want to sort the list alphabetically. Can anyone guide me on this?

```
JS- Fiddle Code

https://jsfiddle.net/22et6sao/619/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example14data| orderBy:'label'" 
  selected-model="example14model" checkboxes="true" 
  extra-settings="example14settings"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/22et6sao/620/

Comment: interestingly this doesn't work it you combine it with group-by